# How to stop adding data to firebase if it already exists?

Tags: android, firebase

I have a Users node and nested under that is an Applied Jobs node. After a person clicks on an apply to job button, the job details get added to Applied Jobs node. However, I don't want to let the user to be able to apply for it again. I also thought about checking if it exists by ID, but I realized that even if the user applies for a job twice, the pushed ID is different. So, I'm not sure how to go about this.

As you can see below, despite being the same entry, the ID is different.

[image]

This is what I tried so far based on similar posts but it doesn't work.

**JobInfo.java**

```
package com.example.oddsynew;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;

import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

public class JobInfo extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    TextView jobName, jobCharge, jobLocation, jobDate, jobTime, jobDesc, jobTasks, addPref, recruiterName;
    ImageView profPic;
    String jobname, jobloc, jobcharge, profpic, startdate, enddate, starttime, endtime, jobdesc, jobtasks, addpref, recruitername, userID;
    ImageButton menuIcon;
    Button requestForHireBtn;
    DatabaseReference myRef, jobNameRef;
    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    FirebaseUser u;
    DrawerLayout drawer;
    NavigationView navigationView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_job_info);

        drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        menuIcon = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.menuIcon);
        requestForHireBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.requestedBtn);
        navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.hamburger_menu);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_gigs);


        menuIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            }
        });

        jobName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.jobName_info);
        jobCharge = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.jobCharge_info);
        jobLocation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.jobLocation_info);
        profPic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.prof_pic_info);
        jobDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.jobDate_info);
        jobTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.jobTime_info);
        jobDesc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.jobDesc);
        jobTasks = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.jobTasks);
        addPref = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.additionalPref);
        recruiterName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.recruiterName_info);

        jobname = getIntent().getStringExtra("jobName");
        jobloc = getIntent().getStringExtra("jobLocation");
        jobcharge = getIntent().getStringExtra("jobCharge");
        profpic = getIntent().getStringExtra("profPic");
        startdate = getIntent().getStringExtra("startDate");
        enddate = getIntent().getStringExtra("endDate");
        starttime = getIntent().getStringExtra("startTime");
        endtime = getIntent().getStringExtra("endTime");
        jobdesc = getIntent().getStringExtra("jobDesc");
        jobtasks = getIntent().getStringExtra("jobTasks");
        addpref = getIntent().getStringExtra("addPref");
        recruitername = getIntent().getStringExtra("recruiterName");

        jobName.setText(jobname);
        jobCharge.setText(jobcharge);
        jobLocation.setText(jobloc);
        jobDate.setText(startdate + " - " + enddate);
        jobTime.setText(starttime + " - " + endtime);
        jobDesc.setText(jobdesc);
        jobTasks.setText(jobtasks);
        addPref.setText(addpref);
        recruiterName.setText(recruitername);

        Picasso.get().load(profpic).into(profPic);

        requestForHireBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
                u = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                userID = u.getUid();

                jobNameRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(userID).child("Applied Jobs").child("job_name");
                ValueEventListener listener = new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        if (!dataSnapshot.equals(jobname)) {
                            myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(userID).child("Applied Jobs").push();
                            myRef.child("job_name").setValue(jobname);
                            myRef.child("job_location").setValue(jobloc);
                            myRef.child("recruiter_name").setValue(recruitername);
                            myRef.child("job_charge").setValue(jobcharge);
                            myRef.child("profile_pic").setValue(profpic);
                            myRef.child("start_date").setValue(startdate);
                            myRef.child("end_date").setValue(enddate);
                            myRef.child("start_time").setValue(starttime);
                            myRef.child("end_time").setValue(endtime);
                            myRef.child("job_desc").setValue(jobdesc);
                            myRef.child("job_tasks").setValue(jobtasks);
                            myRef.child("add_pref").setValue(addpref);
                            requestForHireBtn.setText("Request Sent!");
                            requestForHireBtn.setEnabled(false);
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                        Toast.makeText(JobInfo.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                };
                jobNameRef.addValueEventListener(listener);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.nav_home:
                Intent intent = new Intent(JobInfo.this, Home.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;

            case R.id.nav_gigs:
                Intent intent2 = new Intent(JobInfo.this, MyGigs.class);
                startActivity(intent2);
                break;
        }
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a suggestion. If you can assign a unique id to every job then you can use that id as a parent instead of key generated by firebase.

Comment: Set a criteria like a unique job id for all jobs job id should not change if user apply one time or more then one time. in that way you can check with that job id if job already exists with currently applying job id.

Comment: If job id exists then don't let the user apply again to the same job-id else the user apply.

Comment: Alright thanks for your answers, will try it out soon. I'm wondering though why this post was down voted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options here:

- You can assign every job a unique `jobId`, and whenever a user wants to apply for the job, you check if any of his applied jobs have that `jobId` property.
- Instead of `push()`ing to a completely random key, child to the `jobId`. Such that the structure will be as follows:

```
Users
|
|--- Random Key
    |
    |--- Applied Jobs
        |
        |--- jobId
             |
             |--- ...
```

That way you check if the `Applied Jobs` node has any node whose key is the `jobId`.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it soon.